# Apache2 revese proxy with basic authentication: Client sends wrong "Authorization" header

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to get jupyterhub working again behind an Apache2 reverse proxy with BasicAuth.

Since I updated it to Jupyterhub 1.1, it spits out a number of `Invalid response: 401 Unauthorized` when loading files like `static/lab/vendors~main.52a0cabd079a8f53ed4d.js`.

The Problem is that the client sends requests with the following request header:

```
Authorization: token 0024afb0.................181548ab
```

What it should look like:

```
Authorization: Basic aG9lbH................E5OTQ=
```

Do you have any idea what this might causes?

My current configuration looks like this:

```
<Location /jupyter>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

        AuthName "..."
        AuthType Basic
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        ... # other ldap stuff

        Require valid-user

        # Preserve Host header to avoid cross-origin problems
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        ProxyPass        "http://.../jupyter" keepalive=On
        ProxyPassReverse "http://.../jupyter"
        ProxyPassReverse "https://.../jupyter"

        # JupyterHub
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} Upgrade [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]

        RewriteRule /jupyter/(.*) ws://.../jupyter/$1 [P,L]
        RewriteRule /jupyter/(.*) http://.../jupyter/$1 [P,L]

        # TimeOut 600

</Location>
```